# Switch Statement error and not able displaying the information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The following is the definition on which I am working on it. But I am not able to go further. Switch statement is not working and directly shows the default msg.
Can anybody help me with this ?

Allow the user to choose one of three boxes of fruit (apples, bananas, or cherries) and then ask the quantity of fruit boxes (5, 10, or 15). The cost of each fruit box is as follows: Apples - $0.25, Bananas - $1.60, and Cherries - $2.50. The quantity of fruit boxes should only be requested from the user if a valid fruit box was selected. Otherwise display an error message and exit application. After the type of fruit and quantity is selected display the total price (fruit box price times box quantity). If the user doesn’t select a valid quantity then set the quantity to zero and display an error message.

Updated Code

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("\t Purchasing Fruit System\n");
Console.WriteLine("Select Fruit");
Console.WriteLine("A - Apples ");
Console.WriteLine("B - Bananas ");
Console.WriteLine("C - Cherries ");
Console.Write("Enter Your Selection: ");


string menuSelection = null;
double totalPrice = double.MinValue;
int numOfBoxes = int.MinValue;

//Get Fruit Selection
menuSelection = Console.ReadLine();

//Add a switch statement to set Price
switch (menuSelection.ToLower())
{
    case "a":
        totalPrice = 0.25;
        menuSelection = "Apples";
        break;
    case "b":
        totalPrice = 1.60;
        menuSelection = "Bananas";
        break;
    case "c":
        totalPrice = 2.50;
        menuSelection = "Cherries";
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection !");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
} 
//Display Menu of Quantitites as Long as a Valid
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("How many boxes of {0} do you want ?", menuSelection);
Console.WriteLine("1 - 5 {0}", menuSelection);
Console.WriteLine("2 - 10 {0}", menuSelection);
Console.WriteLine("3 - 15 {0}", menuSelection);
Console.Write("Enter your Selection: ");
//Get Quantity Selection
string value = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse (value, out numOfBoxes) || numOfBoxes < 1 || numOfBoxes > 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection! Quantity is Zero");
    Console.WriteLine();
    return;
}
//Add a switch statement to set Quantity
switch (numOfBoxes)
{
    case 1:
        totalPrice *= 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        totalPrice *= 10;
        break;
    case 3:
        totalPrice *= 15;
        break;
}
//Display Total for Fruit
if (numOfBoxes <=3)
    Console.WriteLine("Quantity is zero Your total is $ 0.00");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Total price of {0} boxes of {1} is: {2}", numOfBoxes, menuSelection, totalPrice);

//Pause Display 
Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue.............");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: In future: "running with error" doesn't help us. Its helpful for us if you include the error and show us what line is causing the error.

Comment: Switch statement is not working

Comment: If I run, it directly shows me "Invalid Selection"

Comment: "A" and "a" are different values unless you tell it to change the casing.

Answer (score 2):

You are using different variable in `switch` statement,I think you want `menuSelection` instead of `switchSelection`

```
switch(menuSelection)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code style I can propose the next code.

```
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\t Purchasing Fruit System\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Select Fruit");
        Console.WriteLine("A - Apples ");
        Console.WriteLine("B - Bananas ");
        Console.WriteLine("C - Cherries ");
        Console.Write("Enter Your Selection: ");


        string menuSelection = null;
        double totalPrice = double.MinValue;
        int numOfBoxes = int.MinValue;

        menuSelection = Console.ReadLine ();

        switch (menuSelection) {
        case "a":
        case "A":
            totalPrice = 0.25;
            menuSelection = "Apples";
            break;
        case "b":
        case "B":
            totalPrice = 1.60;
            menuSelection = "Bananas";
            break;
        case "c":
        case "C":
            totalPrice = 2.50;
            menuSelection = "Cherries";
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine ("Invalid Selection !");
            return;
        }

        //Display Menu of Quantitites as Long as a Valid
        Console.WriteLine("How many boxes of {0} do you want ?", menuSelection);
        Console.WriteLine("1 - 5 {0}", menuSelection);
        Console.WriteLine("2 - 10 {0}", menuSelection);
        Console.WriteLine("3 - 15 {0}", menuSelection);
        Console.Write("Enter your Selection: ");

        //Get Quantity Selection
        string value = Console.ReadLine ();
        if (!int.TryParse (value, out numOfBoxes) || numOfBoxes < 1 || numOfBoxes > 3) {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection !");
            numOfBoxes = 0;
            }

        switch (numOfBoxes) {
        case 1:
            totalPrice *= 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            totalPrice *= 10;
            break;
        case 3:
            totalPrice *= 15;
            break;
        }

        if(numOfBoxes == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Quantity is zero Your total is $ 0.00");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Total price of {0} boxes of {1} is: {2}", numOfBoxes, menuSelection, totalPrice);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean is not working? It is working as expected - exit from the method and since I assume it is a Main() the exits from application. If you meet to show that message for user and wait until he press any key add Console.ReadKey(); (or ReadLine if you prefer) after error message is displayed and before return; statement.

Comment: Here is an example of what I want if invalid quantity selection is entered :

Comment: are you sure? i just checked the code in debugger and it works fine. can you please specify what exactly do you mean saying "is not checking..."?

Comment: can you share your source code? it seems like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: replace return statement after Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection! Quantity is Zero"); Console.WriteLine(); with numOfBoxes = 0; and replace if (numOfBoxes <= 3) with if (numOfBoxes == 0)

Comment: I made the changes as you mentioned but the error message is not printed on the output screen if you enter any number more than 3 , it exist out from the output screen

Comment: most probably you made some other changes. please use my code and after you made sure it works (***and it works***) update output messages. Please mark the answer as correct.